# How to change the number of editor action buttons

Tags: visual-studio-code

In "VSCode" there are these action buttons at the top of the editor area.
The current versions of VSCode seem to show a maximum of 8 of these buttons. The surplus ones are hidden under the `[...]`menu on the far right. By right-clicking you can make individual buttons invisible, which allows other hidden buttons to become visible.
Is it possible to change the number of 8 visible buttons somewhere, especially to increase it, so that I can see more than 8 buttons?
[image: Editor Action Buttons]

By default the area contains only the "share editor right" button, but many extensions fill this area with their own buttons, like the Markdown preview extension, every language provider adds its "debug" and "run" command there, Gitlens adds a whole bunch of them, most of which I turn off again because there are too many.